# How to find pixels per inch (PPI) using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, image-manipulation

I can get PPI for a JPEG image using the following command:

```
$ identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" mypic.jpg 
1600 x 1200 72 PixelsPerInch x 72 PixelsPerInch
```

However, when I run the same command on PNG format I get Pixels Per Centimeter:

```
$ identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" mypic.png 
1600 x 1200 28.35 PixelsPerCentimeter x 28.35 PixelsPerCentimeter
```

Is there a way to change the command to get Pixels Per Inch (PPI) for PNG format as well or perhaps calculate the PPI based on the pixels per centimeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution and units used are stored in the file, so if the resolution is stored in PixelsPerCentimeter, that's how `identify` will display it.  There isn't a way to do the conversion automatically through `identify`.  But it's just cm to inch conversion math:

```
PixelsPerInch = PixelsPerCentimeter * 2.54
```

Comment: Just FYI, but you can actually do the conversion in `identify` now - see my answer. Of course, it may not have been possible when you answered back in the mists of time :-)

Comment: Ahh, I never even gave any though to using an `fx` expression to do that.  I've read some... unflattering things about the speed of `fx` though.

Comment: The speed of `fx` only pertains to when you use `-fx`  with `convert` because it compiles and calls the function for each channel of each pixel, i.e. 3 times per pixel in a potentially large image. When you use it as a `one-off` within the `identify` command, it is as fast as anything.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply add the option

```
-units PixelsPerInch
```

Comment: this is the one I was looking for `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fx` operator and some smart formatting in the output of `identify` like this:

```
identify -format "%[fx:int(resolution.x*2.54)]" image.png
299
```

Of course, the true joy of this is that it is platform-independent, so you don't have to shell out to `dc` on OS X and Linux, or do whatever muppetry is required on Windows to do the maths.

Answer (score 0):

1 inch =~ 2.54 cm. So it is trivial to convert between the two.