# iMagick - DPI of PNG

Tags: php, imagemagick, png

I have an `PNG` that I have saved as 300DPI

When I'm using `iMagick` it returns as 118.11 DPI when using the `getImageResolution()`

Any ideas what I'm possibly doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Users are reporting that this function does not work properly. Which iMagick version are you using?

Comment: According to `convert -v' I'm using `6.7.7-10`

Comment: Please see [How to find pixels per inch (PPI) using ImageMagick](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14632254/2261774) and also the answer below.

Comment: This must be some confusion with inch/centimeters. You can check the "true value" inside the PNG with http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 118.11 is exactly the result of 300 / 2.54. As 1 inch = 2.54 centimeters, it appears iMagick reports dots per centimeter instead of dots per inch. So you just have to multiply the number iMagic gives you by 2.54 to get the original DPI back.

However, in general, DPI on digital raster images don't make much sense, as they do not have a physical size that could be measured in inches or centimeters. Of course, you can set those dimensions on most image formats and they are probably used when printing them, but for every other purpose, this information does not affect the image in any way. Especially when displayed on a computer screen, setting the DPI won't have any effect.

Comment: The DPI values make sense if you send the image to a printer for example. The printer then knows by pixel-size and DPI value(s) which size the image has on paper.

Comment: Ah. I had to use `round()` as the DPI * 2.54 was `299.9994`

Comment: The images are going to be displayed on a Print-ready PDF, therefore I need to check when uploading that they are 300DPI

Comment: @user1970557: Well in that case, this check means *nothing* and the comment by Simon is totally right. This meta-data is useless as you need enough pixels in the image. E.g. I can upload you a 3x3 pixel image at 300 DPI. But you don't want to use that.

Comment: Well, you can do that, but in general, images will probably be set to some fixed size in a document, so the information stored in the image file will not really help that much.

Comment: To expand a bit more on that: most images are stored with an arbitrary resolution, sometimes 72 or 90 DPI, sometimes using something like 150 or 300 DPI. When layouting a document, images are usually set to some desired size, e.g. 3 by 2 inches. This will then determine the resolution, as the pixels will be used to fill those dimensions. So a 4752px x 3168px image will result in a resolution of 1584 DPI (when printed as 3 by 2 inches), even if the image is stored as "300 DPI".

Answer (score 0):

When using a *PNG file*, your version of Imagick returns pixels per centimeter PPC, not dots per inch DPI (pixels per inch PPI). But you are looking for the later.

Please see as well [How to find pixels per inch (PPI) using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14632254/2261774) which outlines the following formula to convert these values:

```
const INCH_PER_CENTIMETER = 2.54; 

$ppi = (int) round($ppcm * INCH_PER_CENTIMETER);
```

Comment: I don't get it. Inches are bigger than centimeters, so your code does exactly the opposite it should do.

You should divide centimeters by CENTIMETERS_PER_INCHES and you'll get inches.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @nkkollaw The constant 2.54 should be called `CENTIMETERS_PER_INCH`, yes, but multiplying PPC by it to get PPI is exactly right: an inch is larger so more pixels fit in it. (More formally, in the dimension pixels / cm, centimeters are in the denominator, so to get something of dimension pixel / in you multiply something of dimensions pixels / cm by something of dimension cm / in.)